# Trying to get mime type on docx files results in application/octet-stream

Tags: php, mime-types, docx

I'm trying to validate file upload on Laravel (docx only) and it keeps failing. After some research it got down to both `$request->file('file')->getMimeType()` and `mime_content_type($request->file('file')->path())` returning `application/octet-stream`.

All the other types I checked return proper mime types, the problem is just with docx. The site is running on apache2.

Is it possible to set the system up to properly identify docx files? And if possible is it reliable at all or should I drop it and make a docx validator using something like PhpWord?

Thanks!

Comment: U can add mimetype in htaccess

Comment: have you tried `getClientMimeType()`

Comment: @chiliNUT yes I did and it returns correct mimetype because it seems to take it from the request headers. It doesn't help much with validation though because Laravel's validation 'mimes' rule makes use of `getMimeType()` which doesn't work with docx (at least for me).

Comment: @MichałSzałapski yeah, I have docx mimetype in /etc/mime.types though. It seems that mime guessers try to look inside the file itself for additional tells and fail to find them.

Answer (score 1):

A MIME attachment with the content type "application/octet-stream" is a binary file. Typically, it will be an application or a document that must be opened in an application.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible to set the system up to properly identify docx files? And if possible is it reliable at all or should I drop it and make a docx validator using something like PhpWord?
```

Laravel uses Symfony, and in turn Symfony has a mime-type guesser which uses the `file` command: [See the Symfony source](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/7.1/src/Symfony/Component/Mime/FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser.php#L33C32-L33C50) (the mime type sent by the browser is unsafe, so it tries to guess it). For some docx/xlsx/etc files, `file` is unable to guess the type of the docx (so returning application/octet-stream).

You can verify this by manually putting the file on the server and then checking its guessed mime type by running `file --mime-type path/tofile`

The file command uses your uses your system's magic database (often at `/etc/magic`, you can find out where your magic database is by typing `file --version`).

The fix is to either update your system so you have a more recent version of `file` and the magic database, or edit your `/etc/magic` file so that includes the contents the following file: https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/msooxml